# ${\rm E}_n$ function for non-integer $n$

Tags: special-functions

The [${\rm E}_n$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/En-Function.html) function implementation in scipy is valid only for positive integer values of $n$, but I have an expression with real $n$ to evaluate. Is there an expression for ${\rm E}_n$ in terms of other special functions (preferably implemented in scipy, but I can do my own homework on that front)?

Answer (score 1):

It can be stated in terms of the [upper incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function):
$$E_\alpha(x)=x^{\alpha-1}\Gamma(1-\alpha,x)$$
Or you can [look on stack overflow!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67591895/python-implementation-of-en-function-for-non-integer-n)